# Stopping Android studio shell process wont stop tests

Tags: shell, android-studio, android-espresso

I am executing a some gradle tasks from a shell script, and am finding that i am unable to kill the process:

[image]

I click stop process like shown in the image, but it doesnt stop the Espresso UI tests from executing on the emulator. the shell script is as simple as "./gradlew spoonDebugAndroidTest"

Is there someway i can stop the tests without closing the emulator, and get rid of the red box saying i have process running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can be fixed by following these steps:

1. Open 'Run' tab in Android Studio
2. Tap 'X' next to test which has just passed

[image: Android Studio guide]

Comment: this is not running a shell script

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, @1ak31sha but it actually *is* a running shell script, just handled by the Android Studio process. This actually got rid of the running processes (that you can see with `CTRL` `F2`) for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute this in Android Studio's Terminal : `./gradlew --stop`. It should stop all running tasks.

Comment: No Luck...Says "No Gradle daemons are running".

Comment: In my case I can stop the gradle daemon, but the test processes are still there. Lame.